# Magento resource model is returning false

Tags: magento

**Problem:**

I'm tracking down a problem where getCollection() on my model is not returning an object but returning false when I run the following code:

```
var_dump(Mage::getResourceModel('referrer/transaction_collection'));
```

Oddly locally its returning an object and not on the server its being deployed on.

**What I have tried:**

- The code is deployed using SVN and is the same code locally and live. This indicated to me it is a case senstive issue (Its been developed on a mac), however I have not been able to find it.
- I've cleared all the caches.
- The module has successfully installed and I can see the table in the database.
- There is nothing in var/log/system.log
- There are no reports being generated in var/report
- Ownership is correct.
- Permission are ok.

I'm running out of ideas how to debug this, are there any Magento gotchas i've missed?

**My Code:**

Referrer/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <TBP_Referrer>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </TBP_Referrer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <referrer>
                <class>TBP_Referrer_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>referrer_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </referrer>
            <referrer_mysql4>
                <class>TBP_Referrer_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <transaction><table>referrer_transactions</table></transaction>
                </entities>
            </referrer_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <referrer_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>TBP_Referrer</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </referrer_setup>
            <referrer_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </referrer_write>
            <referrer_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </referrer_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Referrer/Model/Transaction.php

```
class TBP_Referrer_Model_Transaction extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('referrer/transaction');
    }

}
```

Referrer/Model/mysql4/Transaction.php

```
class TBP_Referrer_Model_Mysql4_Transaction extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract {
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('referrer/transaction', 'transaction_id');
    }
}
```

Referrer/Model/mysql4/Transaction/Collection.php

```
class TBP_Referrer_Model_Mysql4_Transaction_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract {

    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('referrer/transaction');
    }

}
```

Referrer/sql/referrer_setup/install-1.0.php

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
CREATE TABLE referrer_transactions(
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `referrer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `percentage` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `order_id` (`order_id`),
  KEY `referrer_id` (`referrer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
");

$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a while to find it, I was using the wrong Abstract class. Im was using:

Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract

Switching to the following solved it:

Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract

Comment: This didn't solve my issue (yet), but since everything in your problem description fits with me (works fine locally on my mac, gives a non-object "false" on my dev) I thiknk you gave me a good starting point, would never have thought of this!

Comment: This can't be the solution. `Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract` just extends `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` with no competing logic...

Answer (score 1):

in my case it whas NULL because i forgot to create the collection model in /PROY/Test/Resource/Test/Colection.php

```
<?php
class PROY_Test_Model_Resource_Test_Collection extends     Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
 {
     public function _construct()
     {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('test/test');
     }
}
```